# Is it possible to make 2 or more DataBindingComponent?

Tags: android, android-databinding, non-static

I would like to ask is it possible to make 2 or more DataBindingComponent class in android? because i want to escape the static method in binding so i try to use the injection with DataBindingComponent but I got the error of **Class 'AppDataBindingComponent' must be either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'getLoginViewDataBinding' in 'DataBindingComponent'** because of this error I can't make the non-static one.

this is the class which i got the problem

```
public class AppDataBindingComponent implements android.databinding.DataBindingComponent {
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewDataBinding getRecyclerViewDataBinding() {
        return new RecyclerViewDataBinding();
    }
}
```

First binding class

```
public class RecyclerViewDataBinding {

    @BindingAdapter({"app:adapter", "app:data"})
    public void bind(RecyclerView recyclerView, DataAdapter adapter, List<DataModel> data) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.updateData(data);
    }
}
```

Second Binding Class

```
public class LoginViewDataBinding {

    @BindingAdapter({"validation", "errorMsg"})
    public void setErrorEnable(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, StringRule stringRule,
                                      final String errorMsg) {
        Observable<CharSequence> textObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(
                Objects.requireNonNull(textInputLayout.getEditText()));
        compositeDisposable.add(textObservable
                .map(charSequence -> {
                    ......
                })
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .replay(1).refCount()
                .subscribe());
    }

}
```

In the Main Class I call the DataBindingComponent

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DataViewModel dataViewModel;
    private ActivityMainListMvvmBinding activityBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bind();
    }

    private View bind() {
        activityBinding = DataBindingUtil
                .setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main_list_mvvm, new AppDataBindingComponent());
        dataViewModel = new DataViewModel();
        activityBinding.setViewModel(dataViewModel);
        return activityBinding.getRoot();
    }

}
```

The problem is solved if I put **getLoginViewDataBinding**

```
public class AppDataBindingComponent implements android.databinding.DataBindingComponent {
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewDataBinding getRecyclerViewDataBinding() {
        return new RecyclerViewDataBinding();
    }

    @Override
    public LoginViewDataBinding getLoginViewDataBinding() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*the answers that I want is somehow like this: (is this possible?)*

```
public class AppDataBindingComponent implements android.databinding.DataBindingComponent {
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewDataBinding getRecyclerViewDataBinding() {
        return new RecyclerViewDataBinding();
    }
}

public class LoginDataBindingComponent implements android.databinding.DataBindingComponent {
    @Override
    public LoginViewDataBinding getLoginViewDataBinding() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you found any solution for that?

Comment: nope later, i just used mixed programming between the MVVM methods and some MVC method to do...., cause when i whatever solution visible, there is solution for this kind of answers that I want...

Comment: I have found a solution for that. I will post it soon

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public class DataBindingComponent<T> implements android.databinding.DataBindingComponent {
    private T activity;

    public DataBindingComponent(T activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public LoginViewDataBinding getLoginViewDataBinding() {
        return (LoginViewDataBinding) activity;
    }

    public RecyclerViewDataBinding getRecyclerViewDataBinding() {
        return (RecyclerViewDataBinding) activity;
    }
}
```

And than create in both of your class's:

```
new AppDataBindingComponent(this)
```